# how can i change the URL of my localhost

Tags: url, redirect, nginx

I have a website on my ubuntu PC and want to share the URL form : 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
to a more friendly name like : 
`mylocalwebsite.com`.

I edited the /etc/hosts and added this line :
`127.0.0.1     mylocalwebsite.com`

But how can i hide the port?
Can I do it with nginx? how?
 can we do it without nginx? how?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the configuration file. Probably in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ and if this is the default configuration then there should be a file called "default".

> server {
>           listen   8000;
>            }

Change it to:

> server {
>           listen   80;
>            }

Then restart it

> sudo service nginx start

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but I don't have an nginx folder in /etc/. Can i do it without nginx?

Comment: @mamesaye are you using apache?